# How can I present editable text in a command line application?

Tags: ruby, terminal

I'm working on question/answer command line program in Ruby. I would like to let the user edit the question or answer when needed, but I can't find any non-overkill method of doing that. I tried delving into curses but couldn't find any way of presenting editable text there either without coding the whole thing myself which is overkill for a prototype app. I tried using Readline:

```
Readline.pre_input_hook = -> do
  Readline.insert_text "hello.txt"
  Readline.redisplay

  # Remove the hook right away.
  Readline.pre_input_hook = nil
end

input = Readline.readline("Filename: ", false)
```

but it doesn't do anything except print "Filename: ". Python curses seems to have a text-widget "textarea", but ruby doesn't seem to have it.

Answer (score 0):

If the questions are a decent length, it might be worth having an option that just launches `$EDITOR` (vi(m), nano, etc.). Otherwise, look into `libedit` or `libreadline`.

Comment: I'm on ruby 2.0 and would like to limit myself to the standard libraries. I tried the pre_input_hook feature of Readline but it did nothing (look at edited question).

Comment: @Melodius Fair enough, but I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with the Ruby standard library to help much more than this (I'm a Python person). Readline *should* work, but... eh.